# how to filter a list of objects in java 8

Tags: java

how can i write this in java 8 please :

```
ListeTiers tiers = wsTiers.rechercheTiers(serviceContext, params);
       
if(null != tiers) {
  List<Tiers> listeTiers = tiers.getTiers();
  for(TiersP t : listeTiers) {
    if(id.equals(t.getI())) {
      if(t.getActivite != null) {
        if(t.getActivite.getCode() != null)
          result.setCode(t.getActivite().getCode());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is not clear.

Comment: That looks like valid java syntax to me; Did you mean that you want a way to accomplish the same behavior as a lambda expression?

Comment: `if(t.getActivite != null) {` Shouldn't that be: `if(t.getActivite() != null) {` ?

Comment: I believe `for(TiersP t : listeTiers) {` should be `for(Tiers t : listeTiers) {`.  And don't worry about using streams for this.  Stick with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't - the operation isn't functional (you're calling a setter and mutating state).

You can hack it, but this shouldn't be considered an improvement compared to what you already have. Also, you have a **field** named `getActivite`? And also a getter with the same name? That's... crazy.

```
public void updateResultCode(Something wsTiers) {
  ListeTiers tiers = wsTiers.rechercheTiers(serviceContext, params);
      
  if (null != tiers) {
      tiers.getTiers().stream()
        .filter(t -> id.equals(t.getI())
        .filter(t -> t.getActivite != null)
        .map(t -> t.getActivite.getCode())
        .filter(c -> c != null)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(c -> result.setCode(c);
  }
}
```

I'd write it like this:

```
public void updateResultCode(Something wsTiers) {
  ListeTiers tiers = wsTiers.rechercheTiers(serviceContext, params);
  if (tiers == null) return;

  for(TiersP t : tiers.getTiers()) {
    if(!id.equals(t.getI())) continue;
    if(t.getActivite == null || t.getActivite.getCode() == null) continue;
    result.setCode(t.getActivite().getCode());
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```java
tiers.getTiers()
     .stream()
     .filter(t -> id.equals(t.getI()))
     .filter(t -> t.getActivite().getCode() != null)
     .forEach(t -> result.setCode(t.getActivite().getCode()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that

```
ListeTiers tiers = wsTiers.rechercheTiers(serviceContext, params);
       
if(null != tiers) {
  List<Tiers> listeTiers = tiers.getTiers()
    .stream()
    .filter(t -> id.equals(t.getI()))
    .map(TiersP::getActivite)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Activite::getCode) // Or however your class is named
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .foreach(c -> result.setCode(c));
}
```